# Set user to admin in firebase

Tags: firebase

I transferred a website from one firebase account to a newly created one for the client on a separate email. I want the new firebase account to have control of the billing but they need to be admin. How do I set this new account to be admin? Is there an easy way such as when you set a new user to owner?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic), you need to assign the **owner** role to this new account (i.e. this new project member) using the Firebase console or the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Owner is different then admin. I disconnected my account from it with the new email setup as owner and I get a notification that this new email is not admin. Thus not allowing me to handle billing.

Comment: You can assign the `billing.admin` role to your user through the IAM page in the Google Cloud console. More details in the doc at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access

Comment: appreciate the help